# Convert HTTP JSON body response to map in Go

Tags: http, dictionary, go, httpresponse

I am trying to convert HTTP JSON body response to `map[string]interface{}` in Go.

This is the code I wrote:

```
func fromHTTPResponse(httpResponse *http.Response, errMsg string )(APIResponse, error){
    temp, _ := strconv.Atoi(httpResponse.Status)

    var data map[string]interface{}
    resp, errResp := json.Marshal(httpResponse.Body)
    defer httpResponse.Body.Close()
    if errResp != nil {
        return APIResponse{}, errResp
    }

    err := json.Unmarshal(resp, &data)
    if err != nil {
        return APIResponse{}, err
    }

    return APIResponse{httpResponse.Status, data, (temp == OK_RESPONE_CODE), errMsg, map[string]interface{}{} }, nil
}
```

I successfully connect to the server. The response's body contains JSON data. After running the code, data points to `nil`, why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`http.Response.Body` is `io.ReadCloser`. So use this:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(httpResponse.Body).Decode(&data)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `*http.Response.Body` is of type `io.ReadCloser`. And you are not using right method to read the body data and to convert it into `[]byte`. Try to use this:

```
resp, errResp := ioutil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)
```